# How can I add two variables on one line in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to modify some HAML code and would like to output two different variables on the same line. How can I achieve this?

```
%h3= @level.name " $" @level.price
```

Ideally, I want the output to be in this format: `Individual $35`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `@level.price` held as a string or float?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
%h3= "#{@level.name} $#{@level.price}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write it as

```
%h3 #{@level.name} $#{@level.price}
```

The above is same as:

```
%h3= "#{@level.name} $#{@level.price}"
```

[Ruby Interpolation: #{}](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_)

> Ruby code can also be interpolated within plain text using #{}, similarly to Ruby string interpolation.